# C# -Converting int ToString("X6") gives 8 characters

Tags: c#, ms-word, hex

I am tring to convert a wdColor to rgb # color by this flowing code. I am converting the enum wdColor result to hex by ToString("x6").But Sometimes it gives me back a 8 lenght string, and i need 6 length string to convert it to rgb;

```
 var num = -603914241;
 var numToHex = y.ToString("x6");
```

gives "dc00ffff" that has 8 charectars.

Comment: `"x6"` format string guarantees that it should be *at least* **6** hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input number is too big to be represented using just 6 characters. `x6` means that the output should be at least 6 characters long, padding by zeros as necessary to meet that minimum length - but if the input is too big then it'll use as many characters as necessary to represent it.

Answer (score 1):

According to manual

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#XFormatString

> The hexadecimal ("X") format specifier converts a number to a string
>   of hexadecimal digits. The case of the format specifier indicates
>   whether to use uppercase or lowercase characters for hexadecimal
>   digits that are greater than 9. For example, use "X" to produce
>   "ABCDEF", and "x" to produce "abcdef". This format is supported only
>   for integral types.
>
> The precision specifier indicates the **minimum number of digits** desired
>   in the resulting string. If required, the number is padded with zeros
>   to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision
>   specifier.

In your case it means that `x6` guarantees *at least* (not *exactly*) **6** hexadecimal digits